# Disable emmiting empty list elements in Xml Serializer in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I would like to disable emmiting empty elements in Xml in List.
I know about PropertyNameSpecified pattern but I don't know how to apply it to the list.

I have list of elements and it is being serialized. Some of those elements are empty and are producing empty Xml elements in that list (what I don't want).

My sample code:

```
public class ConditionsCollectionModel
{
    [XmlElement("forbidden")]
    public List<ForbiddenModel> ForbiddenCollection { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("required")]
    public List<RequiredModel> RequiredCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ForbiddenModel : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Value = reader.ReadElementString("forbidden");
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(Value);
    }
}

public class RuleModel
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("conditions")]
    public ConditionsCollectionModel Conditions { get; set; }
}
```

It produces Xml in form like:

```
<rule>
    <name>SR</name>
    <conditions>
        <forbidden />
        <forbidden />
        <forbidden>Ftest</forbidden>
        <required>test</required>
        <required>test2</required>
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

I don't want those empty elements in `conditions` list.

Comment: A sample Code on how the values are assigned to the Rule Model Class could be helpful!

Comment: @KrishnaPS Model is deserialized from xml. And values are added or edited via code. Then it is serialized again. I want to avoid serialization of empty elements.

Comment: So you aren't assigning any values or you have no control on this XML generation.

Comment: If the Value comes from a List, you can use Linq to remove the empty elements from the List, this would solve the problems.

Answer (score 4):

The question is rather old but I experienced the same problem today. So for anybody reading this topic, this is the solution that works for me.

Add "ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}"

```
public class ConditionsCollectionModel
{
    [XmlElement("forbidden")]
    public List<ForbiddenModel> ForbiddenCollection { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("required")]
    public List<RequiredModel> RequiredCollection { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeForbiddenCollection(){
    return (ForbiddenCollection !=null && ForbiddenCollection.Count>0);

}
```

see: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Since ForbiddenCollection is list of Forbidden Class, you can set value of an empty ForbiddenClass object to null while inserting into the List.

Comment: This is sample code. Those elements contain empty string. (I don't have control over this part of code).